# Openpyxl or Pandas, which is better at reading data from a excel file and returning corresponding values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, data-analysis

Hello **Stack OF** Community,

*
Basically my goal is to extract values from an excel file, after reading through data from another column.*

**
Thickness**  of parcel, with values for example - **[0.12, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.15]** (Heading: Thickness (mm))
**Weight** of parcel, with values for example - **[4.000, 3.500, 2.500, 4.500, 5.000, 2.000]** (Heading: Weight (KG))

Excel File:
**Thickness**   **Weight**
0.12             4.000
0.12             3.500
0.13             2.500
0.14             4.500
0.14             5.000
0.15             2.000

Looking to generate this using **Python**:
Thickness   Weight   Parcels
0.12             7.500     2 Parcels
0.13             2.500     1 Parcels
0.14             9.500     2 Parcels
0.15             2.000     1 Parcels

TOTAL:         21.500     6 Parcels

The user will be shown all the current values of **Thickness Available** and will be allowed to **input** a *single thickness value to get its weight* or *a range and get its weight*.

So anyone of you who can recommend me how can this task be accomplished easily and efficiently.

I would be very grateful for your advice.

*Please note: I have only done Python Programming Language.*

Thank You.

I have learned Openpyxl but also got to know that Pandas is an efficent tool for Data Analysis, so please let me know!

Arigato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas actually uses openpyxl as well as well as some other engines  inside. You can check engines field in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). I think that reading and manipulations are easier with pandas, but if you need some advanced formatting, you will need to use openpyxl directly. (For basic cases pandas is enough).

Here is a basic example for your problem. You will need to change formatting for you needs.

```
import pandas as pd

# uncomment to read the file
# df = pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', index_col=None)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Thikness": [0.12, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.15],
    "Weight": [4.000, 3.500, 2.500, 4.500, 5.000, 2.000, ],
})

res = df.groupby(["Thikness"], as_index=False).agg(
    Weight=('Weight', sum),
    Count=('Weight', 'count'),
)

# write excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('tmp.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
res.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Comment: Thank you @Dimitrius,

I will check into Pandas over the next few weeks and hopefully start building my program after having the basic understanding.

From where do you recommend should I start for Pandas ? 

- Should I start from the basics and then focus more towards the excel part ?

Thanks!

Comment: @Code-Killer Pandas is quite user-friendly and intuitive. I guess you can find any beginners guide, or beginners guide for data science, and get basics in several hours. Than you can google whatever you don't know and you going to be ok. I cannot recommend any particular guide, there thousands of them.

Answer (score 2):

pandas is using openpyxl depending on the file extension under the hood in pandas.DataFrame.read_excel or pandas.DataFrame.to_excel anyways.
You can probably go with pandas as you just need the one method. The performance difference (if there even is one) shouldn't affect you in any way.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: Hey @8bnjmn,

Thank you for you advice, I'll try learning Pandas and then built this program. Where do you think can I learn Pandas most efficently, please guide me.

Thanks.